# I cannot use jupyter notebooks in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am using pycharm with a virtual environment set in preferences. That environment has installed python 2.7.13. I have installed anaconda in the virtual environment, which contains jupyter. I had the professional version but have allowed the subscription to lapse.

According to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html I can create a notebook by opening the project window and using command-N, When I do this, I CAN select jupiter notebook but there is no way to enter the filename that they require.

Trying it another way, I use File->New->Python File   and, for the name use test.ipynb. Pycharm accepts it but puts on a '.py' suffix, treating it as a normal python code file: test.ipynb.py.

Any ideas on how I get this to work?

Answer (score -1):

I think u should try File->New->Jupyter Notebook, this works for me.